# How can you add a string to an onclick function based on a link/filter clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filtering, adobe-analytics

Would like to use jQuery or js.

I have filters that change the way a page displays.  I am tracking the clicks on the images that are filtered by using a onclick on the anchor tag.  I want to pass the link/filter that was selected along with the text I am currently housing in the onClick.

I have the filters and trackLink working.  I just need to append the data-filter value to the onclick in the anchor tag.

Here is the example to shine the light on the situation...

Filters

```
<a href="#" data-filter=".optionone">Option One</a>
<a href="#" data-filter=".optiontwo">Option Two</a>
```

Content Being filtered - same page

```
<div class="item">
    <a onclick="trackLink('Text I Want', 'Text I want')" href="1.aspx">
        <img src="1.jpg" alt="1" />
        <div>Test</div>
    </a>
</div>  

<div class="item">
    <a onclick="trackLink('Text I Want', 'Text I want')" href="2.aspx">
        <img src="2.jpg" alt="2" />
        <div>Test</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

What I want - Pass the data-filter value.

```
<div class="item">
    <a onclick="trackLink('Text I Want', 'Text I want' + the filter name as it is being click passed)" href="1.aspx">
        <img src="1.jpg" alt="1" />
        <div>Test</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Your need more javascript for this to do anything.  This is just HTML.

Comment: Right - have the filters and the trackLink function working, but how do I append the data-filter to it?

Comment: There's a lot of info missing... If you want to get your data attribute, you just have to do `$(selector).attr("data-filter")`

Comment: @pmrotule How do you take that and add it to <a onclick=blahBlah + data-filter>

Comment: @RooksStrife I put it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really append text like that inside of a function inside of an HTML element.

What I would do is switch up the HTML some by adding a class to the filters, and moving the "Text I want"s to their own data value:

```
<a href="#" class="filter" data-filter=".optionone">Option One</a>
<a href="#" class="filter" data-filter=".optiontwo">Option Two</a>
...
<div class="item"><a data-first-text="Text I Want" data-second-text="Text I want" href="1.aspx"><img src="1.jpg" alt="1" /><div>Test</div></a></div>
```

Then use jQuery to call your function:

```
var filter_text;

$('a.filter').click(function(event) {
    // set the filter text to whatever the filter is
    filter_text = $(this).data('filter');
});

$('.item a').click(function(event) {
    var first_text = $(this).data('first-text');
    var second_text = $(this).data('second-text');

    // call trackLink with your desired texts
    trackLink(first_text, second_text + filter_text);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/050uqd8p/)

Comment: So can I then add onclick="trackLink()" or trackLink(first_text, second_text + filter_text) to the HTML links?  That way onclick the value is passed to Adobe Omniture (tracking).

Comment: With this you don't need the onclick function in the link. jQuery calls it for you.

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery, you can use something like below. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish_88/zxa32f7d/) here

```
$('a').click(function(){
alert($(this).attr('data-filter'));
});
```

Comment: How do you take the value of the clicked filter and add it onto anchor tag like - <a onclick=blahBlah + data-filter>

Comment: using this keyword, please view DEMO

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you doing this way:

```
$(".item a").click(function () {
    var value = $(this).attr("data-filter"); // 'this' = the a element being clicked
    trackLink('text you want', 'text you want' + value);
});
```

Finally remove the trackLink function from your onClick even on the a tag

Answer (score 0):

Include jQuery in the HEAD of your document

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Then, to create a global function, you go like this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    getDataFilter = function(selector){

        return $(selector).attr("data-filter");
    }

    anotherFunction = function(dataFilter){

        // do something
    }
});
```

And your tag will look like this

```
onclick="anotherFunction(getDataFilter('.item a'));"
```

Or if you want a pure javascript solution:

```
document.querySelector('.item a').getAttribute("data-filter");
```

Hope it helps!